# General doubts on Navigation Controller - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some general question about navigation controller. I have pushed a table view with navigation controller. (now table view showing) If I click on back button of navigation controller it brings me back to main view, now the memory allocated for table view will get released automatically. Do we need to do extra?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, as long as you don't maintain a reference to the object, you can safely assume Cocoa Touch will do the right thing. When things aren't drawn on the screen, the APIs generally don't just hold on to them for no reason, so if you're not holding on to them either you're fine.

"Holding on" in this context either means "keeping a reference to" if you're using ARC or "not `release`ing" if you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Before ARC: When you add a UIViewController to the navigation controller's stack you need to release the view controller after pushing the it onto the stack.

No need to do this if your project is ARC enabled. Read up more on ARC.